# How to identify elevation from a DEM (.asc/.tif)?

Tags: geospatial, netlogo

I already figured out how to use a DEM as world in Netlogo:

```
  globals
[ elevation-dataset
]

patches-own
[ elevation
]

turtles-own
[
]

extensions [ gis ]


to setup
  ca
  set elevation-dataset gis:load-dataset "srtm_43_05.asc"
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of elevation-dataset))
  gis:paint elevation-dataset 0
  reset-ticks
end
```

Now, I want to place agents in this landscape. The landscape is partly land, partly water and I want the agents to be just on the land part.
I assume that the water would have certain elevation values and I should be able to tell the agents to be  set only on patches that are above this certain elevation. Any idea if or how that could work?
I have a .tiff of the DEM and the file I used for setting up the world is an .asc. I do not know which would be best for the problem.